# Validar datos antes de ejecutar una función

Tags: javascript, funciones, validación

Estoy intentando validar un input que solo puede recibir números positivos, no se pueden introducir letras, tampoco números negativos, tampoco se puede dejar vacía la casilla y quiero que me muestre un error dependiendo de que caso se ejecute, el problema que tengo es que se me ejecutan los 3 mensajes a la vez y no consigo que se ejecute de forma independiente según el error que provoque.

Este es el código:

```
    function convertir(a, b) {
  a || b <= 0
    ? alert("debes introducir un numero mayor a 0")
    : !a || !b
    ? alert("solo puedes poner numeros")
    : a || b === ""
    ? alert("no has puesto nada introduce numeros")
    : convertir();
  resultado = a * b;
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Aclara el lenguaje

Comment: Está acotando las condiciones al poner ; , debe concatenarlas como lo dice el operador ternario [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) , por otra parte, se supone que las validaciones son primero y por último el resultado, también veo que la función compartir recibe obligatoriamente 2 parámetros, cosa que no veo al llamar esa función.

Comment: he configurado el codigo pero no hace nada de lo q quiero

Comment: Es JavaScript lo estoy usando para cuando inserte esas validaciones en un input me muestre los alert que van en cada condicion,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo tengo chicos al final era esto

```
function convertir(a, b) {
  a === "" || b === ""
    ? alert("has dejado los campos vacios")
    : a <= 0 || b <= 0
    ? alert(" introduce numeros mayor a 0")
    : isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)
    ? alert(" has puesto letras solo puedes poner numeros")
    : (resultado = a * b);
  return resultado;
}
```